# Laravel whereHas not between or doesn't exsists

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have to write query where I need to get salons where there is no reservations so I am writing this:

```
Salon::whereHas('reservationsSalons', function($q) {
    $q->whereNotBetween('start_time', [request()->start_time, request()->end_time]);
})
->get();
```

But the problem is I am not getting salons where there is no reservations. So I need something like

```
->orwhereNotHas('reservationsSalons')
```

Comment: There's a method `whereDoesntHave()` which you can use in an or clause, see here: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_whereDoesntHave

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer to your question is use `whereDoesntHave`.

The long answer however doesn't is only known by you. We can't see your code so we can only speculate what the real issue is. Left for me, I think your query is already correct assuming you're trying to get reservations that are not included in the input time.

The correct way to find out the issue is to use `DB::getQueryLog()` to inspect the query being generated by Laravel/Eloquent builder and ensure it's the correct query.

Also, you may find that you may be able to get a faster query using a raw query builder or a more native query.